# Get the last primary key from table with no auto increment

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a primary key and for some reason i was advised not to use the AUTO_INCREMENT flag.
So every time i have to insert a new entry i search for the last value inserted (highest value) of the primary key. 
Then i increment it by 1 to get a new ID.
Now the problem i face is, when inserting the first entry, there is no data in the table.

Can anyone suggest the optimal way to check 
if data exists in table, 
if not set id as 1 and insert new row, 
else get the last id from table, increment it by 1 and then insert new row.

PS: New to mysql so having difficulty with its syntax.

Comment: What is the problem with using `AUTO_INCREMENT`? Because that is the solution to your problem.

Comment: 'for some reason i cannot set it to auto increment.' - what have you tried that failed or caused you problems?

Comment: There is a MySQL manual and 1000's of online tutorials :)

Comment: @Progman I have been told not to use it, and look for an alternative. Don't know why they don't want me to use auto Increment. One reason that i can think of is to keep track of ID, which in case of auto increment gets tough. And also when they want to have customized ID.

Comment: Be careful of race conditions! If two concurrent sessions both read MAX(id)+1 in their own transaction, they will both try to insert the same value. The way to work around this is to execute all inserts serially, but this can cause a bottleneck in your application. This is why auto_increment is a better solution.

Comment: @ChudamaniKhadka You should ask your source or "they" first why they think you shouldn't use `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Otherwise you are doing all that what is already implemented in `AUTO_INCREMENT` (with all the problems there might be).

Comment: @ChudamaniKhadka Is this a school assignment? That's the only reason I can think of to be "told not to use" the clear and obvious solution; an exercise in finding alternative (if inferior) solutions.

Comment: @UncaAlby Not the school assignment, but sort of the same, I am under mysql training, and i have been told to do so by the trainer.

Comment: Then ask the trainer for help. Thats what training is for!

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for letting me know, though the situation i have been explained by the trainer does not allow the race condition to pop up, as there will be only one person handling the operations, but thank you, i will be careful for race condition in future.

Comment: @ChudamaniKhadka Don't be "careful in the future"! When you get out of training, do it the _right_ way!  Use AUTO_INCREMENT, and let the Database take care of it! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your statement '*i search for the last value inserted (highest value) of the primary key*', I presume that you're currently doing something like this to get the maximum existing ID:

```
SELECT MAX(id_column) + 1 FROM my_table
```

If you have an empty table, this will of course return `NULL`.  In that case, just handle the `NULL` using `IFNULL` to return 0 if there is no maximum value:

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id_column), 0) + 1 FROM my_table
```

This will output 1 as the next identifier if the table has no rows.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer to the question as stated, altho it would still be interesting to learn why AUTO_INCREMENT is not allowed.

Comment: @UncaAlby Except is makes no reference to the obvious Race potential this would introduce and as such may be considered a little dangerous as it stands

Answer (score 1):

I've given this more thought, and it turns out there **is** a way to generate a unique primary key without using Auto Increment or worrying about race conditions, so long as you are willing and able to use a 36 byte primary key (or, alternatively, a 128 bit binary).

The solution (at least as of MySQL 5.5) is the **UUID**, which stands for Universal Unique Identifier.

You would use it thus:

```
CREATE TABLE uu_table (
    id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    {other interesting columns}
)
```

Then insert new rows thus:

```
INSERT INTO uu_table VALUES (UUID(), 'Name of this Row', {other interesting values});
```

The UUID() function is guaranteed to generate a unique key 99.99{bunch more 9's}% of the time, even if generated on independent systems. That's its whole purpose, to be as unique as snowflake patterns, no matter where it is created.

There are pros and cons to this method. Best to read up on it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

It is basically a 128 bit number, which you can save as a binary value after conversion from the 36 characters. I believe some versions of MySQL come with functions for that purpose. That would use less space in your database than 36 bytes, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.